# Indexing engine

Tags: indexing, lucene, search-engine, information-retrieval

I'm developing context discover system - which is mix of searching and suggestions. 
Currently I'm looking for library for indexing. 
After some investigation I stayed on **Lucene** and **Terrier** and found Indri not comfortable.

What are the downsides of both? What problem I can meet while using them?

Is it true that Terrier doesn't have incremental indexing (every time new document is added, I need to rebuild and reindex everything)?

My requirements are:
 - easy adding new documents
 - easy score methods injection
 - quiet well defined model

And one more thing: is Terrier still active? I haven't seen any update since 10/03/2010 [terrier changelog](http://terrier.org/docs/current/whats_new.html)

Comment: How you will access the index? Directly by using java or with something like an proxy (for example Solr & lucene)? Because Solr provides features to improve lucene (for example the elevation feature)

Comment: I want to programming in java, so the access will be direct.

Answer (score 1):

What sort of database are you going to be using?  Lucene, in my experience, is much better documented than Terrier.

Here's an article comparing Lucene and Terrier:

http://text-analytics.blogspot.com/2011/05/java-based-retrieval-toolkits.html

Comment: Hi, I saw this article before. The question about incremental indexing goes from this article.
I think the database is not the point as both have support for new outstanding databases (lucandra, and hdoop -> for scalability).